Why Tailwind CSS doesn't works with public/*.html files in my Ruby on Rails project
I'm using Tailwind CSS for my Ruby on Rails project, the CSS works fine with all the layouts in views but it doesn't works with public/*.html files in my project.
I have a 404.html page and a 500.html page in public directory where i need Tailwind CSS to work.
This is my tailwind.config.js file, I even added ./public/**/*.html but it still doesn't works:
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './app/views/**/*.html.erb',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/assets/stylesheets/**/*.css',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js',
    './public/**/*.html'
  ],
  safelist: [
    'w-64',
    'w-1/2',
    'rounded-l-lg',
    'rounded-r-lg',
    'bg-gray-200',
    'grid-cols-4',
    'grid-cols-7',
    'h-6',
    'leading-6',
    'h-9',
    'leading-9',
    'shadow-lg',
    'bg-opacity-50',
    'dark:bg-opacity-80'
  ],
  darkMode: "class",
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        nagano: {
          white: '#FFFFFF',
          black: '#000000',
          'light-grey': '#E0E0DB',
          'dark-grey': '#2A2829',
          'light-red': '#B82126',
          'dark-red': '#8F1417',
          'backdrop': '#efefef',
          red: {
            10: "#FADBDC",
            100: "#8F1417"
          }
        },
        primary: {
          50: "#FCEDED",
          100: "#FADCDC",
          200: "#F7C9CA",
          300: "#F2A6A7",
          400: "#EB7072",
          500: "#E64C4F",
          600: "#D61F22",
          700: "#B3191C",
          800: "#8F1417",
          900: "#6B0F11"
        }
      },
      fontFamily: {
        'sans': ['Inter', 'ui-sans-serif', 'system-ui', '-apple-system', 'system-ui', 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', 'Noto Sans', 'sans-serif', 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Noto Color Emoji'],
        'body': ['Inter', 'ui-sans-serif', 'system-ui', '-apple-system', 'system-ui', 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', 'Noto Sans', 'sans-serif', 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Noto Color Emoji'],
        'mono': ['ui-monospace', 'SFMono-Regular', 'Menlo', 'Monaco', 'Consolas', 'Liberation Mono', 'Courier New', 'monospace']
      },
      transitionProperty: {
        'width': 'width'
      },
      textDecoration: ['active'],
      minWidth: {
        'kanban': '28rem'
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('flowbite/plugin')({
      charts: true,
    }),
  ],
}



Look at the generated HTML for those public files. Chances are they do not include any reference to the tailwind css files because by default these files are static and will not include lines like <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>. If you'd like to customize the error pages generally it is better to do so through the application itself. Try searching "Rails Custom Error Pages" as there are plenty of resources to explain implementation.
